# How can embedded neo4j have a custom logback file?

Tags: java, neo4j, logback

We are using neo4j 1.9.5 in embedded mode in a webapp and I would like to configure logback for it.

I've seen that the class org.neo4j.kernel.logging.LogbackService reads a neo4j-logback.xml file from the classpath, so I was able to configure neo4j logging that way.

But what I would like to be able to do is point neo4j to a logback.xml file on location on disk, so I can put the config somewhere outside our webcontainer, is such a thing possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not possible. Because in init method in org.neo4j.kernel.logging.LogbackService class they using

```
URL resource = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource( logbackConfigurationFilename );
```

to read the config file. So they config file must be in the classpath.You cannot point some other disk location.

Comment: Thought as much. Thanks for the confirmation. If someone is interested, I created an issue for this https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/1827